# How does scrollbar become transparent?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to understand how my vertical scrollbar became transparent:

[image]

The relevant code is:

```
$background-image-with-gradient: 
    linear-gradient(
        to right top, 
        rgba(248, 12, 12, 0.235), 
        rgba(17, 226, 128, 0.235)),
        url("https://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/18380-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg");

@mixin pseudo-element-background {
    content: ""; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top; /* When resizing the window, the top of image stays attached to top */
    //background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    //bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.outer {
  width: 30em;
}

.auth-form-frame-container {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 2em 4em rgba(black, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.auth-form-frame {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    
    &:before {
        @include pseudo-element-background;
        background-image: $background-image-with-gradient;
        background-position: center;  
    }
}
```

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="auth-form-frame-container">
  <div class="auth-form-frame">
    <h1>Line 1</h1>
    <h1>Line 2</h1>
    <h1>Line 3</h1>
    <h1>Line 4</h1>
    <h1>Line 5</h1>
    <h1>Line 6</h1>
    <h1>Line 7</h1>
    <h1>Line 8</h1>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

I substituted the input elements by h1 headers, but the actual content should be irrelevant. I have put this code into [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/PoJYEbq?editors=1100), but the scrollbar shows very nicely there:

[image]

What could cause the scrollbar to become transparent in my website?

Comment: What system/browser are you testing on. Running your code (but with the SCSS 'translated' to pure CSS for clarity) on Windows10 Edge the scrollbar does not become transparent. Could you try making your code into a Stackoverflow snippet which we can run to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @AHaworth Opera. However, it is the same browser on which I run the CodePen example. I assume that there is some other relevant piece in my code (which is in ReactJs), but just cannot figure out what it could be and cannot post the whole thing...

Answer (score 2):

There is something called `::-webkit-scrollbar`,
with this, you can specify properties of the scrollbar.

I created a jsfiddle where you can see how this works.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emielvdv/upse2fqt/4/)

This is probably way out of topic, but I cannot ask any more questions because stackoverflow blocked me.
I would highly appreciate it if you upvote my questions and answers so I can ask questions.

Hope I helped you out and thank you in advance!

Comment: But I did not use it, so it could not be responsible for my scrollbar becoming transparent...